# PHP loop and get lowest price

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I need please some help with the looping through a set of objects that represents flight offers from country `a` to `b` and each route may contain multiple offers. I want to grab the lowest flight offer for each route... I just don't know how to do it inside the loop. This [Answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345307/php-retrieve-minimum-and-maximum-values-in-a-2d-associative-array) I tried works will giving me the lowest price but how can I get the whole array of this price? I know it sounds stupid but im stuck.

```
 $results = array();
 $offers = R::getAll( "SELECT * FROM fares WHERE available = 1 LIMIT 4");
```

`$offers` returned data set sample posted here on [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a2p9482m/)

then I did the following :

```
 foreach($offers as $key=>$val){
            $results ['city'] = $val["name"];
            $results ['country'] = $val["parent_name"];
            $off = json_decode($val["Flights"]);
            var_dump($off);

            // here I need to loop through $off & grab the lowest
        }

   return $results;
```

`$off` dump returns the following

```
object(stdClass)#60 (1) {
  ["BEY"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#61 (6) {
      ["price"]=>
      int(490)
      ["airline"]=>
      string(2) "ME"
      ["flight_number"]=>
      int(276)
      ["departure_at"]=>
      string(20) "2015-07-11T12:20:00Z"
      ["return_at"]=>
      string(20) "2015-07-18T08:20:00Z"
      ["expires_at"]=>
      string(20) "2015-06-30T14:31:43Z"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#62 (6) {
      ["price"]=>
      int(639)
      ["airline"]=>
      string(2) "FZ"
      ["flight_number"]=>
      int(716)
      ["departure_at"]=>
      string(20) "2015-07-05T15:50:00Z"
      ["return_at"]=>
      string(20) "2015-07-12T04:30:00Z"
      ["expires_at"]=>
      string(20) "2015-07-01T08:11:49Z"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#63 (6) {
      ["price"]=>
      int(472)
      ["airline"]=>
      string(2) "EY"
      ["flight_number"]=>
      int(299)
      ["departure_at"]=>
      string(20) "2015-07-18T03:10:00Z"
      ["return_at"]=>
      string(20) "2015-07-28T04:30:00Z"
      ["expires_at"]=>
      string(20) "2015-06-30T12:20:30Z"
    }
    [3]=>
    object(stdClass)#64 (6) {
      ["price"]=>
      int(2045)
      ["airline"]=>
      string(2) "SU"
      ["flight_number"]=>
      int(1861)
      ["departure_at"]=>
      string(20) "2015-07-11T14:50:00Z"
      ["return_at"]=>
      string(20) "2015-07-18T05:05:00Z"
      ["expires_at"]=>
      string(20) "2015-06-30T14:31:43Z"
    }
  }
} 

object(stdClass)#65 (1) {
  ["BEY"]=>
  object(stdClass)#66 (3) {
    ["1"]=>
    object(stdClass)#67 (6) {
      ["price"]=>
      int(1903)
      ["airline"]=>
      string(2) "EY"
      ["flight_number"]=>
      int(461)
      ["departure_at"]=>
      string(20) "2015-07-17T22:40:00Z"
      ["return_at"]=>
      string(20) "2015-07-31T04:30:00Z"
      ["expires_at"]=>
      string(20) "2015-07-01T10:46:41Z"
    }
    ["2"]=>
    object(stdClass)#68 (6) {
      ["price"]=>
      int(1535)
      ["airline"]=>
      string(2) "QF"
      ["flight_number"]=>
      int(341)
      ["departure_at"]=>
      string(20) "2015-07-17T11:00:00Z"
      ["return_at"]=>
      string(20) "2015-07-31T22:55:00Z"
      ["expires_at"]=>
      string(20) "2015-07-01T10:46:41Z"
    }
    ["3"]=>
    object(stdClass)#69 (6) {
      ["price"]=>
      int(2321)
      ["airline"]=>
      string(2) "AY"
      ["flight_number"]=>
      int(5014)
      ["departure_at"]=>
      string(20) "2015-07-17T11:45:00Z"
      ["return_at"]=>
      string(20) "2015-07-31T22:55:00Z"
      ["expires_at"]=>
      string(20) "2015-07-01T10:46:41Z"
    }
  }
}
ect .....
```

Any idea ?

Thanks alot!

Comment: As per the result of `$off` , it is not a single object. It contains more than one object.. So what is the exact response you want ?

Comment: @Awena, Can you share the table structure that you are using and please show the data in pure array, instead of objects.

Comment: Grabbing the lowest flight offer for each route seems like a perfect job for SQL.

Comment: @Purushottamzende give me a sec. I don't think SQL can query JSON data, can it? Did you look at the fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($offers as $key=>$val){
    $results ['city'] = $val["name"];
    $results ['country'] = $val["parent_name"];

    $off = json_decode($val["Flights"], true); //note the true

    $lowest = PHP_INT_MAX;
    foreach ($off['BEY'] as $item)
        $lowest = min($item['price'], $lowest);

    //now $lowest is the lowest price

    $lowest_item = null;
    foreach ($off['BEY'] as $item)
        if ($item['price'] == $lowest) {
            $lowest_item = $item;
            break;
        }

    //now you can do something with $lowest_item, like $lowest_item['flight_number']
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! finally someone reads a question before posting! I appreciate it Dave. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I think you can skip the last loop.

```
<?php
foreach ($offers as $key => $val) {
    $results['city'] = $val["name"];
    $results['country'] = $val["parent_name"];
    $off = json_decode($val["Flights"], true);

    $lowest = PHP_INT_MAX;
    $lowest_item = null;
    foreach ($off['BEY'] as $item) {
        $lowest = min($item['price'], $lowest);
        if ($item['price'] == $lowest) {
            $lowest_item = $item;
        }
    }
    // Now $lowest is the lowest price and 
    // you can do something with $lowest_item, 
    // like $lowest_item['flight_number'].
}
```